# Can't resize internal frame until after its minimized and un minimized

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

To reproduce the problem: Run the code and see you can not move/resize/maximize the internal frames. Minimize and un minimize a frame, and observe that you can now move, resize, and maximize the internal frames.

How can I get it to be movable and re sizable from creation? Thanks!

Also, I'm using netbeans latest version to auto generate this code.

```
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class SelectorFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SelectorFrame2
     */
    public SelectorFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jInternalFrame4 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame5 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jInternalFrame4.setIconifiable(true);
        jInternalFrame4.setMaximizable(true);
        jInternalFrame4.setResizable(true);
        jInternalFrame4.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        jInternalFrame4.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame4.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame4.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame4Layout);
        jInternalFrame4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 275, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 179, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jInternalFrame5.setIconifiable(true);
        jInternalFrame5.setMaximizable(true);
        jInternalFrame5.setResizable(true);
        jInternalFrame5.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        jInternalFrame5.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame5.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame5.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame5Layout);
        jInternalFrame5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 275, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 171, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDesktopPane1);
        jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
        jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jDesktopPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(209, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(117, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jDesktopPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(233, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(174, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jDesktopPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jDesktopPane1.setLayer(jInternalFrame4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jDesktopPane1.setLayer(jInternalFrame5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectorFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectorFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectorFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectorFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SelectorFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame4;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame5;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `GroupLayout` for the `JDesktopPane` you let the group layout manager define the positions and sizes of the `JInternalPane`s. Instead of using a group layout for the `JDesktopPane` you have to define initial sizes and positions by code.

I recommend that you read through the [Java Swing Tutorial, the chapter "How to Use Internal Frames"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)